# Elasticsearch query to match a pattern and replace it with regex

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-aggregation, kibana-7

I have to get the TOP 5 hit APIs/Urls and display with the http statuses of each url and I am able to do it in a way with the below extraction query

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "range": {
                    "@timestamp": {
                        "from": "now-15m",
                        "to": "now",
                        "include_lower": true,
                        "include_upper": true,
                        "boost": 1
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "adjust_pure_negative": true,
        "boost": 1
    }
},
"aggregations": {
    "Url": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "data.url.keyword",
            "size": 5,
            "min_doc_count": 1,
            "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
            "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
            "order": [
                {
                    "_count": "desc"
                },
                {
                    "_key": "asc"
                }
            ]
        },
        "aggregations": {
            "Status": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "data.response.status",
                    "size": 5,
                    "min_doc_count": 1,
                    "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                    "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                    "order": [
                        {
                            "_count": "desc"
                        },
                        {
                            "_key": "asc"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Output :

```
"aggregations": {
"Url": {
    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 940,
    "sum_other_doc_count": 52374,
    "buckets": [
        {
            "Status": {
                "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                "buckets": [
                    {
                        "doc_count": 3,
                        "key": 200
                    },
                    {
                        "doc_count": 254,
                        "key": 400
                    }
                ]
            },
            "doc_count": 3515,
            "key": "/account/me/"
        },
        {
            "Status": {
                "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                "buckets": [
                    {
                        "doc_count": 3376,
                        "key": 200
                    }
                ]
            },
            "doc_count": 3385,
            "key": "/PlanDetails"
        },
        {
            "Status": {
                "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                "buckets": [
                    {
                        "doc_count": 3282,
                        "key": 200
                    }
                ]
            },
            "doc_count": 3282,
            "key": "/evaluation"
        },
        {
            "Status": {
                "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                "buckets": [
                    {
                        "doc_count": 3205,
                        "key": 200
                    }
                ]
            },
            "doc_count": 3205,
            "key": "/user/me"
        },
        {
            "Status": {
                "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                "buckets": [
                    {
                        "doc_count": 3055,
                        "key": 200
                    }
                ]
            },
            "doc_count": 3055,
            "key": "/user"
        }
    ]
}
}
}
```

But I have few URL where user ID comes inbetween the URLs.
For eg URLs like

```
/account/me/3417375321062014.cust
DJXXODKNPA1581975RI/PlanDetails
KXVEIPBYSR1597110677RI/payment
```

Because of distinct user ID inside the URL, elastic search considers these as separate one.

User ID is a mix of alphabets and numbers, sometimes only numbers and few only alphabets.

I need to replace these userID's in URL and count them as one

Lets say there are two hits with 200 status for /payment

```
DJXXODKNPA1583201975RI/payment
KXVEIPBYSR1597110677RI/payment
```

I should be able to replace the user ID with * and count as one API so I get output like

```
*/payment 200:2
```

But now it considers these as distinct URL/API, because of this I am unable to get the correct Top 5 Hit urls/APIs.

Any idea on this would be a great help. Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for regex to capture the two ID's from `DJXXODKNPA1583201975RI/payment` and `KXVEIPBYSR1597110677RI/payment` ?  I'm not sure what you're looking for.

Comment: @Aaron Yes thats just an example, So i have user ID's in between my URL. Need to capture user IDs (DJXXODKNPA1583201975RI,KXVEIPBYSR1597110677RI) and replace them with "*" and take the count of /payment as one. Since each /payment URL has a unique user ID it takes 1 count each and because of that my TOP 5 HIT API output is incorrect.

Comment: From what you've provided the input needs to be `DJXXODKNPA1583201975RI/payment,KXVEIPBYSR1597110677RI/payment` and the output needs to be "*/payment".  Therefore a regex of `.*` with a replacement string of `*/payment` will work.

Comment: @AaronJ Can you show me an example of adding this regex and replacement string to my extraction query. I tried but am unable to do it.

Comment: `$output = "*/payment"`

Comment: Your description of your input and expected output is unclear.